# How to compute the mean over rows till a variable changes and repeat?

Tags: spss

Given a very huge table of the following format (e.g. snippet):

`Subject, Condition, VPH, Task, Round, Item, Decision, Self, Other, RT
 1,       1,         1,   SVO,  0,     0,    4,        2.5,  2.0,   8.598
 1,       1,         1,   SVO,  1,     5,    3,        4.1,  3.4,   7.785
 1,       1,         1,   SVO,  2,     4,    3,        3.2,  3.4,   15.713
 2,       2,         1,   SVO,  0,     0,    4,        2.5,  2.0,   15.439
 2,       2,         1,   SVO,  1,     2,    7,        4.9,  2.3,   30.777
 2,       2,         1,   SVO,  2,     3,    8,        4.3,  4.3,   13.549
 3,       3,         1,   SVO,  0,     0,    5,        2.8,  1.5,   9.066
 ...` (And so on)

Needed: Compute the mean over all rounds for self and others for each subject.

What i have so far:
I sorted the about 100mb `.txt` file using `bash sort` so the subject and the related rounds appear after each other (like the example shows). After that i imported the `.txt` file into SPSS24. Right now i have no idea to write a function that computes for each subject the mean of variable self and others over the three rounds. E.g.: (some pseudo-code)

`for n = 1 to last_subject do:
   get row self where lines have line_subject as n
   compute mean over these content
   write result as new variable self_mean as new variable after variabel RT at line n
   increase n by one`

As i am totally new to SPSS i really appreciate detailed help. I am also satisfied with references that specifically attend to computation over rows (i found lots of stuff over columns).

Thank you very much!

**Edit: example output**
After computing the table should look like this:

`Subject, Mean_Self, Mean_Others
 1,       3.27,      2.9
 2,       ...,       ...
 3,

 ...` (And so on)
So now we computed the Mean_Self from the top example like so:
`mean(2.5 + 4.1 + 3.2)` 
**where:** 
2.5 was used from line 1 of Variable Self 
4.1 was used from line 2 of Variable Self
3.2 was used from line 3 of Variable Self

2.5 was **not** used from line 4 of Variable Self because Variable Subject changed, there for we want to repeat the process with the new Subject (here 2) until it changes again. The results should create a table like the one above. Same procedure for Variable Other.

Comment: Adding some examples of expected output would help better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi, eli-k thank you for your help. i will add an example output, just give me a moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right what you need is the `aggregate` command. `aggregate` can create a new dataset/file with your aggregated data, or add the aggregated data to your active dataset, like you described above:

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=Subject
  /Self_mean=MEAN(Self) 
  /Other_mean=MEAN(Other).
```

In order to get the new variables in a new, separate tabe, look up other AGGREGATE options, e.g. `/OUTFILE=*` (removing `MODE=ADDVARIABLES`) will result in the new aggregated data replacing the original file in the window, while `/OUTFILE="path/filename"` will save the aggregated data to a file.

Comment: Hi eli-k thank you for your help. Sadly i am not sure if your example helps. I updated my Question with a example how it should result.

Comment: Okay i got a step into the syntax and have to say thank you! Your answer ist so amazingly right, thank you!!!

Comment: Happy to help. see some additions I made to fit other options in your edit.